# iOS / Swift: Add UI Component at coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

new to Swift/objC and I'm writing an app in Swift that appends multiple touch points(as CGPoint) to an array and then selects a random point from that array.

I want to add a basic UI component (circle or rectangle) to that point in the view, but I've searched around and can't seem to find any resources.

I've added the code that appends the touches to an array and selects the random point with the output below.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
// add touches to array
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let location = touch.locationInView(view)
    arr.append(location)
}

// select random touch from array
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arr.count)))
let foo = arr[randomIndex]
print(foo) >> (29.0, 213.0)
```

Comment: Circles and rectangles are not UI elements, they are shapes. You need to create a custom class that draws shapes in it's drawRect method, or better yet, that contains and manages custom Shape objects. This would be a good Swift OOP learning project.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod thanks for linking to that question, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams great! Hope you don't mind that I vote to close yours as a duplicate

Comment: @MaxMacLeod yeah go for it